# Why Fedora Workstation 29 send out automatic DNS requests to fedoraproject.org every 3 minutes?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, pihole

I installed [PiHole](https://pi-hole.net) on my Raspberry Pi and set it as DNS server for my Fedora Workstation.

Now I notice that my Fedora Workstation 29 setup requests `fedoraproject.org` about every 3 minutes. I find this strange and so I Googled and found nothing.

Which service could it be that is requesting them and why? So it doesn’t seem to be Gnome Software (PackageKit) because I turned it off and the requests are still made.

edit:

fixed. was the automatically enabled captive portal check. can be deactivated as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419422/wifi-disable-hotspot-login-screen)

Comment: Please do not put "Fixed: …" in the question. If you've found an answer, then post it as an answer.